# Cannot call method 'getWindowHeight' of undefined after sencha build package

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1, sencha-cmd

I have developed an app which requires some container to be drawn based of height & width of device so I have used

```
[Ext.Viewport.getWindowHeight()][1] &     
Ext.Viewport.getWindowWidth()
```

at few places in my code and it was working fine until I did `sencha app build package`. When I tried to open the packaged app I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getWindowHeight' of undefined       app.js:1 (anonymous function)
```

Similar issue was raised in Sencha forum in past but it is unanswered: 
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?240494-Call-method-getWindowHeight-of-undefined

As per Sencha docs : **Ext.Viewport is a instance created when you use Ext.setup** and **if you use Ext.onReady, this instance of Ext.Viewport will not be created**. But in my app.js I am using `Ext.application()` not `Ext.setup` or `Ext.onReady`,

is that the reason singleton is not created? If yes how can I fix it?

I am using Sencha Cmd Ver 3.0.2.288 & Sencha Touch ver 2.1.1

Comment: not sure why you think you'll get different answers here... same people man this forum as sencha one..??

Comment: Hope is a good thing, maybe the best of things, and no good thing ever dies

Answer (score 0):

my solution to the problem was using low-level javascript instead of Sencha's framework.

as described here:
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow

in my case, using

```
window.innerHeight
```

was enough as my users won't be using IE.